# Local Authentication not changing view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, fingerprint, touch-id

I'm having an issue with changing view controllers in local authentication. When all the code executes in the success if statement the view controller does not change even though I'm telling it to. I've tried everything that I know but nothing works. Here is my local authentication code.

```
  let authentication = LAContext()
  var authenticationError: NSError?

  authentication.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authenticationError)

  if (authenticationError != nil) {
    // Authentication Not available for this version of iOS
    self.gotoMainViewController()
  } else {
    authentication.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "Access Passy using Touch ID") {
      (success, error) in
      if (error != nil) {
        // There was an error - user likley pressed cancel
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        if (success) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.gotoMainViewController()
          }
        } else {
          self.showFailedTouchIDError.showAlert()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is the gotoMainViewController() code.

```
  func gotoMainViewController() {
   let viewController = MainViewController()
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
  }
```

Comment: Post your `gotoMainViewController()` method code

Comment: I have updated the question to include to code for the gotoMainViewController method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! It seems that local authentication needs a boolean IF statement to be wrapped around all of the code. I'm not sure if this is true...but it worked for me.